# Need to SUM turnover by part_name, then SELECT MAX(Turnover) by segment - NEEDS TO SUM FIRST BY ONE CRITERIA, THEN MAX BY ANOTHER CRITERIA

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with segment, part_name, turnover, as such:

```
segment      part_name  cust_id    turnover
A            blue       1           4202  
A            red        1           625342
A            blue       9           369
B            orange     6           31323 
B            orange     8           4678
B            red        8           27847 
C            red        3           13001 
C            blue       4           3097
C            blue       5           423
C            blue       2           9753
```

I have tried quite a few inner joins that have not worked and after trolling the internet for an answer for a while, decided to turn to SO

the actual result should only be 3 lines (one per segment) with the part_name that has the sum of the maximum turnover ( the turnovers need to be added by part_name, and then the part name with the largest turnover sum needs to be returned - NOT JUST the maximum turnover in a line, but a SUM of the turnover by part_name)

```
A    red             625342 
B    orange          36001 
C    blue            13273
```

THANK YOU.

Comment: Something against yellow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `row_number()` :

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by segment order by turnover desc) as seq
      from table t
     ) t
where seq = 1;
```

If you have a ties with `turnover` then use `dense_rank()` instead.

**EDIT :** I misread the question you want window function with `row_number()`

```
select t.segment, t.part_name, t.t_turnover as turnover
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by segment order by t_turnover desc) as seq
      from (select t.*, sum(turnover) over (partition by segment, part_name) as t_turnover 
            from table t
           ) t
     ) t
where seq = 1;
```

Comment: Hey, thank you. Sorry, this returns 109 lines. It does not give me the part_name with the highest turnover in each of the three segments.

Comment: @bosschonk. . .  You need only `segment` in `partition` clause.

Comment: Sorry, this is not summing up the turnover by part_name at first stage.

Comment: Sorry, Yogesh, that is not working either. It does not like the syntax.

Comment: @bosschonk. . . Inner table alias not declared. fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much, Yogesh. This has solved the problem. Thank you very much!